# Выдвигающееся (слайд) меню на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, html, javascript, css, php

Приветствую.

Появилась задача, как можно сделать слайд-меню для сайта.

К примеру, сверху сайта есть полоса. Если её потянуть вниз, там будет отображаться какая-то информация.

Если можно, в примере.

Заранее благодарю

Comment: Вам именно надо, чтобы была возможность потянуть или просто при наведении курсора\клике, чтобы меню выезжало вниз? Если второй вариант, то http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: именно чтоб тянуть. Где-то видел подобную реализацию, но где уже не помню)

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/emzQYB

or

http://codepen.io/search?q=menu&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false